# Can't connect to a remote wcf service from IIS

Tags: wcf, iis

I am able to connect to a remote WCF service from a console or a website/webapplication running on a VS dev server successfully.  However, when I try to connect from an IIS hosted website I'm getting the following error. Any idea?

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 12.11.121.12:80

Answer (score 4):

This error:

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Means that a connection request successfully got through to the target machine (it isn't a firewall issue), on a given port and the target machine was not listening for incoming connections on that port, so the OS refused the connection attempt.

The rest of your error identifies the machine `12.11.121.12` and the port number `80` that the connection was attempted on.

The error indicates that a server isn't running on the target machine.  If you *know* a server is running on the machine you're attempting to connect to, because you can connect to it from another application, then this suggests that your connection details are misconfigured in the website.

So, some things to check:

- Are there any differences between the app.config/web.config configuration details for the target webservice?  Specifically, the machine name (12.11.121.12) and the port number (80) would seem potentials.
- Are you running the IIS hosted website on the same machine as the console/web application that works?  If not, do both machines resolve the target server name (are you using `someserver.org` for example rather than `12.11.121.12` and it is being resolved to a different IP because one server is external facing and the other is internal?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I started looking into the configuration especially after your's reply. Our computers are configured through a proxy so I thought that may be an issue.. I changed some parameters in the binding element like bypassProxyOnLocal="false" useDefaultWebProxy="false" proxyAddress="http://proxyaddress:portno" in the web.config and at-once things started working. I'm wondering why no body thought about that.

Comment: @Vijaya Anand: Glad you got it working.  Proxy’s are definitely one of the easiest ways to end up talking to a different machine to the one you thought you were :)

Comment: @Mark: A few things around site etiquette, since your problem seems to be resolved. If you found my answer useful in resolving your problem, it's generally polite to upvote it. If you aren't going to accept it and/or award the bounty (which is reasonable since I didn't mention your exact problem), then you should consider posting an answer of your own and accepting that instead to indicate the problem has been resolved and how.  If on the other hand you are hoping for further help, you may want to post an update to your question to indicate what issues you still have.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like a permissions (authentication issue) since the app pool is running under a different user (machine) by default.  Since WCF uses the authentication token, I will bet this is your issue.  Try setting the identity of the pool to the same user as the console, and I bet it will work fine.

Comment: This error 'target machine actively refused it' happens if the target machine is not listening on the port that the connection attempt is being made on (in this case because of the proxy settings, see the ops comment under my answer).  If it were a permissions issue, the error would be more likely to be something like 'permission denied' or 'authentication failure', but this level of validation doesn't take place until *after* the connection has been established.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely I got this error when useDefaultWebProxy was "true" from a Web App, but exactly the same code and settings worked ok in a unit test class.

It turns out that the Web App was using the web-browser proxy (corporate policy) of https://foo/bar:1234.  When I set this explicitely using:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name=...
          useDefaultWebProxy="false" proxyAddress="https://foo/bar:1234"
       ...
```

I got the error:

> The ServicePointManager does not support proxies with the https scheme

So I changed the proxy address to http, not https, and it worked.